# how do I write API tests in Typescript for Cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, cypress, web-api-testing

So I am trying to write a API tests for contacts api which means :

1. First test will create a contact
   2.Second test will check the created contact using get contacts list
   3.Third test will update the contact
   4.Fourth test will delete that contact.

this is what I written in test file :

```
import { getContactList, delContact, createContact, updateContact } from "../base/RequestType";
import { HeadersType } from "../base/HeaderType";
import * as url from '../../fixtures/Url.json';

describe('mfax Api end-points', () => {
    let contactId
        it('Get contacts list', () => {

            createContact(url.endpoint.createcontact,HeadersType.contentJSON)
                .then(({ status, body }) => {
                    expect(status).to.eq(200);

                    expect(body).to.have.property('uuid');
                    
                    const contactId = body.uuid;

                    return contactId;
                })
                .then((contactId) => {
                    return getContactList(url.endpoint.getcontacts, HeadersType.contentJSON)
                        .then(({ status, body }) => {
                            expect(status).to.eq(200);

                            const { count, rows } = body;

                            expect(Array.isArray(rows)).eq(true);

                            const filteredCount = rows.filter(contact => contact.uuid === contactId).length;

                            expect(filteredCount).to.eq(1);

                            return contactId;
                        })
                })
                .then((contactId) => {

                    updateContact(
                        contactId,
                        {
                            'name':'newname',
                        },
                        HeadersType.contentJSON,
                    )
                        .then(({status, body}) => {
                            expect(status).to.eq(200);

                            const {
                                name,
                            } = body;

                            expect(name).to.eq("newname");
                        })
                        
                })
                .then((contactId) => {
                delContact(
                    contactId,
                    HeadersType.contentJSON,
                )
            
                .then((resp) => {
                    expect(resp.status).to .eq(204);
                })
            })
        })


})
```

Fourth test doesn't seem to work properly and i am unable to understand why.

```
Status: 404 - Not Found
Headers: {
"date": "Sat, 08 Oct 2022 02:27:45 GMT",
"content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
"content-length": "64",
"connection": "keep-alive",
"x-powered-by": "Express",
"access-control-allow-origin": "*",
"x-ratelimit-limit": "60",
"x-ratelimit-remaining": "56",
"x-ratelimit-reset": "1665196125",
"cache-control": "no-store",
"pragma": "no-cache",
"x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
"access-control-expose-headers": "Content-Disposition",
"x-server-version": "4.11.0",
"etag": "W/"40-dpCqarGGuD+Tpa/d+EZwPf5l9LU"",
"strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
}
Body: {
"error": {
"name": "NotFoundError",
"message": "Contact not found"
}
}
```

I also tried to search some examples where I could learn to get id from API response and use it in multiple tests . Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After `updateContact()` you would need to `return contactId`, similar to the `getContactList()` and `getContactList()` sections.

```js
createContact(...)
...
.then((contactId) => {
  return updateContact(
    ..
  ).then(({ status, body }) => {
    expect(status).to.eq(200);
    const { name } = body;
    expect(name).to.eq("newname");

    return contactId
  });
})
.then((contactId) => {
  delContact(contactId, HeadersType.contentJSON).then((resp) => {
    expect(resp.status).to.eq(204);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , Can you please share the courses name where I can learn Typescript?